# Where does mozilla sync / weave save its passphrase

Tags: firefox, sync, bookmarks

I've uninstalled the mozilla sync addon and forgot to save my passphrase. Maybe the passphrase is stored somewhere in the config files or the registry so I can recover my bookmarks.
Does anyone know where mozilla saves the configuration for its addons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Firefox's **`Error Console`** from `Tools` menu (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>).

Click on `Clear` and type in the following code inside the code box:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://services-sync/service.js"); Weave.Service.passphrase
```

When you hit Enter, your *passphrase* will appear. If you change "passphrase" to "password" and hit Enter again, then your *password* will appear.

Comment: It seems my passphrase got cleared after the addon deinstallation. So it may be the solution when sync is installed and configured, so I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks